# Mean squred error interpretation in LSTM model (bidirectional or multiparallel)

Tags: python, keras, lstm, mean-square-error

I'm playing with time series and Keras LSTM 1) bidirectional and 2) multiparallel model. I'm saving
the best model according to the "mean_squared_error" metrics. My dataset is normalized with MinMaxScaler (default range from 0 to 1). Mean squared error is 0.02 on the test part of the dataset. Does it mean that my model's mean error is 14% - that is 0.02^0.5. Is it a good practical interpretation of the model's precision?

Suppose I want to predict fourth value in this sequence:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

So my x_test and y_test looks like this:

```
[10 20 30] 40
[20 30 40] 50
[30 40 50] 60
[40 50 60] 70
[50 60 70] 80
[60 70 80] 90
```

And the code:

```
cp = [ModelCheckpoint(filepath=path+"/epochBi.h5", monitor='mean_squared_error', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)]
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics= ['mean_squared_error'])
history_callback = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, verbose=1, callbacks=cp)
model.load_weights(path+"/epochBi.h5")
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
```

Suppose that I evaluate on original dataset, how would I interpret the MSE=0.02?

Comment: have you looked at my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE** The question was updated and hence a new comment

Again, your MSE of 0.2 DOES NOT MEAN 14% of anything, it is just a scalar and you cannot take it as a percentage of your ground truth.

> Is it a good practical interpretation of the model's precision?

I would ask this question differently, `what does it mean to me?`

Well, looking at your target values that range from 40 to 90, you can say that on average, your error was 0.14. Now if you need more details, it means that when you were predicting 40, you guessed 39.86, when 50 --> 50.14, 60--> 59.86, etc. But this is on average.

Hope you got the idea by now

---

Let's have a look at the formula of mean squared error (MSE):

[image]

So it is just the average of the squared difference between the predicted and the actual data points. In your case, sqaure root of MSE (RMSE) is  0.02^0.5 or around 0.14 (rounded).

> Does it mean that my model mean error is 14%

No, you cannot say that your the error is 14% when you get the loss of 0.14. 0.14 is just the value of the error, and your each individual errors could have been negative or positive, making their sum zero but not their squared sum.

> Is it good practical interpretation of the model precision?

Depends on your goals. You usually measure accuracy depending on some other metrics too like MAE, R sqaured and others. Assuming you did not rescale your data to its original magnitude, then there is no way to know how good or bad this is on absolute terms. So I suggest you measure MSE on your rescaled data and then decide, if not done so already.

Comment: I had an evaluation on the original data as you suggest. Though I was thinking that it is not regular procedure. Further, I was thinking that it will be better to get MSE in 0 to 1 interval and then applicate result on a original values.

I understand what you wrote and I also looked at the equation when I wrote the 14% error if my model have 0.02 MSE. I will ask you to try another example which proofs that it isn't matter if I used original or scaled values.
Ymean=0.6; Y1 = 0.5; MSE=(0.5-0.6)^2=0.01
if original data are scaled*1000 then
Ymean=600; Y1 = 500; MSE=(500-600)^2=10000USD

Comment: your interpretation of the formula is not correct. 

It is not the squared difference of the mean of Yhat and Y, but of each individual points. Let's say we have two data points: Yhat [0.5, 0.6] and Y[1, 1].  Yhat_average= 0.55 Y_average = 1, MSE_by_your_formula = ((0.45)^2)/2, MSE_by_the_original = ((0.5)^2+(0.6)^2)/2

I hope you got the idea

Comment: Thank you on your patience with me. You help me alot but I need your explanation once again on bidirectional LSTM model, if you have a time. So I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks again on patience and precise answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are using MSE that measure the distance between your model answer and actual ones. Maybe your model never exactly guesses your target but its guess is enough near to target. So, you can not compute a percent or accuracy here.
For more information, you may read about the differences between regression and classification models.

Comment: So what would you write about MSE explanation of LSTM model. p.s. Look at the toy example in a comment above.